# GraphQL backend service call another GraphQL backend service

Tags: node.js, graphql, microservices, apollo, apollo-server

Here is my situation, I have GraphQL backend service A, GraphQL backend service B, and a frontend portal.

When frontend sends an HTTP request to service A, service A needs to call service B for getting some data.

The call like this:

```js
const query = gql`
  query user {
    id
    name
  }
`;
const user = await gqlclient.query({query});
```

As you can see, service A is some kind of client to make a GraphQL query to service B. I don't think it's a good way, because when service B handles the HTTP request from service A, it will perform schema verification, middleware, and other code again. It's unnecessary and will cost the resource and affect performance.

I see [apollo federation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/introduction/),  but it seems more useful for the frontend. My service A calls service B is some kind of internal service call. So, how can I handle this situation? thanks.

Comment: If the query that is sent to service B doesn't need additional data from service A is better you sent it directly from frontend.

Comment: @Nux This business logic has to be done in the backend. You can imagine this is a step in a database transaction.

Comment: Then Service B will have to do validation because that's how graphql works unless you create a REST endpoint that will need no validation and call it from service A like calling some external API.
But all in all is better graphql to be a single source of all client's data.